# How to add a new return type in LINQ

Tags: linq-to-sql

Hi I need to add a new stored procedure in my file dmbl I can to add but I do not know how to add a new return type

[please see the image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhUUa.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was result the root cause was my stored procedure used a #table instead of @table
http://riteshkk2000.blogspot.com/2010/08/error-unknown-return-type-return-types.html